# Smarty PHP Conditional Help

Tags: php, smarty

When `$SENDER_LAST_WORD_PLAYED` or `$SENDER_LAST_WORD_SCORE` are blank I want the sentence stating "First word played: $SENDER_LAST_WORD_PLAYED for $SENDER_LAST_WORD_SCORE points" to not be printed. So far I've written it so that only if `$SENDER_LAST_WORD_PLAYED` is not present it will not print the sentence but i would also like to put `$SENDER_LAST_WORD_SCORE` validation on it.

Here's my code right now:

```
{if isset($SENDER_LAST_WORD_PLAYED) && !empty($SENDER_LAST_WORD_PLAYED)}
First word played: '{$SENDER_LAST_WORD_PLAYED|truncate:15:"..."|capitalize}' for %%SENDER_LAST_WORD_SCORE%% points
{else} {/if}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Another shot:

```
{if isset($SENDER_LAST_WORD_PLAYED) && !empty($SENDER_LAST_WORD_PLAYED) && isset(SENDER_LAST_WORD_SCORE) && !empty(SENDER_LAST_WORD_SCORE)}
```

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends on what you want to consider "empty". Check out the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: Try the edit - checking both variables. In your example, you were only checking `$SENDER_LAST_WORD_PLAYED` and not `$SENDER_LAST_WORD_SCORE`

Comment: That's more what I was looking for. Thanks!